# Overriding a default init function in iOS

Tags: ios

originally, I have a default init function

```
 -(id) init
   {
    if (self=[super init])
    {
      ......
     }
    return self;
   }
```

However, I like to override the init function to pass in custom objects or other objects
  like

```
 -(id) initWithScore:(NSString*) score
    {
    if (self=[super init])
```

Now there is an error saying [super init] function can only be called with -(id) init function.

So what do I do to fix it so I can pass in objects and also use self=[super init]?

***Error:Cannot assign to self outside of a method in the init family.***

Comment: Please paste the exact error.

Comment: Also tell us which class you are deriving from.

Comment: jason, maybe it is not a bad idea to accept my asnwer as the as the one solving the problem in case it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

I was trying to convert a projet to ARC and after creating a new one and including the files from the old one - one of the issues i got was

> Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family

The selector name MUST begin with `init` - not only that in my case the init selector was:

```
-(id)initwithPage:(unsigned)pageNum {...}
```

Notice the small 'w'.

I have changed it to:

```
-(id)initWithPage:(unsigned)pageNum {...}
```

Notice the capital 'W'!

My problem was solved.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I needed to capitalize the 'W'

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, What and amazing solution :D
Thank you so much

Comment: It definitely helps!  Thx

Comment: Great tip, it fixed my problem... but REALLY Apple..?  You couldn't have given us a clearer error message, telling us "your selector must begin with 'init'" ?!   Grrrrr..  Hate this environment...

Comment: Thank you so much..It was very annoying. We deserve more meaningful error message than this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an object of type id in your new method.

Suppose you have declare an NSString *myscore property, you will write something like this:

```
-(id) initWithScore:(NSString*) score
 {
    self=[super init];
    if (self)
    {
       self.myscore = score;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Your first method, it still complained Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family.   The second method,that class wouldn't run.

Comment: can u edit your post and show us your full initWithScore method?

Comment: also check your typo is correct: http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?topic=6790.0

Comment: Your answer is wrong. This line: self=[super init]; still give same error " Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family". You should verify your answer in XCode next time.